# Cannot seem to align <nav> bar items in Bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I don't know exactly where i'm going wrong here, I cannot seem to align my  bar items on a new site i have built, I have put 2  bars at the top to show what I have tried on: https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/ what i'm trying to make it look like is this: https://www.the-golfer-guys.com/ on this site it looks very neat, everything is aligned in the center and it looks good on mobile too. I don't even know how I managed to get that one right to be honest.

I have tried both of these attempts to center the :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark border-bottom" id="mainNav">
    
    <div class="container-fluid"> 

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #fff"></i>
        </button>    

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="collapsibleNavbar">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= $url ?>">
                <img src="<?= $url ?>images/img-logo.png" alt="<?= $url ?>" class="d-block d-sm-inline-block mw-100 mx-auto">
            </a>

            <!-- TEMPLATE_NAVBAR -->
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li>    
                <form action="index.php" method="get" class="d-flex mb-3">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. health or golf etc" required>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ms-2"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>  
            </li>           
            </ul> 

        </div>

    </div>
    
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark border-bottom" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #fff"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <a class="navbar-brand me-3" href="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/">
            <img src="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/images/img-logo.png" alt="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/" class="mw-100" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
          </a>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill flex-column flex-sm-row mb-3" style="display: flex; gap: 10px;">   
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/" class="nav-link ">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/about.php" class="nav-link ">About</a></li>  
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.digitalproductscorner.com/contact.php" class="nav-link ">Contact</a></li>  
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li>    
            <form action="index.php" method="get" class="d-flex mb-3">
              <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. health or golf etc" required>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ms-2"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>  
          </li>           
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The only thing that looks right is the top  search box, it is positioned correctly it seems, my css is fairly simple so far:

```
.nav-fill .nav-item {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.ms-auto {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

footer {
    background-color: black;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I even tried to copy the code line by line on this site: https://www.the-golfer-guys.com/ but it still looks off on the first site which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your requirement's, you would like the nav-pills to be centered. To achieve this remove the margin-left from the nav-pills element and add the below CSS.

```
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    justify-content: center;
```

You will also need to update the .nav-fill .nav-item to use flex: 0 0 auto;

I would suggest looking into how flex box works in more depth, this site will give you a better understanding of how flexbox works https://flexboxfroggy.com/